# windows local disk (c) always show 0 byte

Tags: local-storage

> I am using local disk c: and I try to insert file into local folder but it show "no enough space on local disk" .Then I remove almost 1 gb from local folder still shows 0 byte free.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the drive. Mainly this happened when drive corrupted.